# Cannot Query DB Eclipse e.g. Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby, sqlexception, eclipse-kepler

I'm new to using DB within eclipse and I've ran into a bit of an issue. I'm able to create a db connection (and hence create a table), but when I try to query said table, I get the following: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:

I'm using the static call to the JDBC_URL that I used in the first place, so im confused why this is happening. Below shows two main classes. The first one works fine (the creation of the table) but the second one throws the above error. Note I have the derby.jar in the lib folder of my project.

Class A) Works fine

```
public class CreateDB {

        public static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:zadb;create=true";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        connection
                .createStatement()
                .execute(
                        "create table channels(channel varchar(20), topic varchar(20), videoclip varchar(20))");
        connection.createStatement().execute(
                "insert into channels values "
                        + "('oodp', 'creational', 'singleton'), "
                        + "('oodp', 'creational', 'factory method'), "
                        + "('oodp', 'creational', 'abstract factory')");
        System.out
                .println("Table was created and the records were successfully inserted...");
    }
}
```

Class B) (SQL exception is thrown)

```
public class QueryDB {

    public static final String SQL_STATEMENT = "Select * from Channels";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CreateDB.JDBC_URL);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL_STATEMENT);
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();

        for(int x = 1; x <= columnCount; x++){
            System.out.print(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(x) + "|");
        }
        while(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println();
            for(int x = 1; x <= columnCount; x++){ System.out.print(resultSet.getString(x) + "|");}
        }

        if(statement!=null) statement.close();
        if(connection!=null) connection.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely you aren't executing them with the same classpath. Check the run settings in Eclipse.